# how to change visible of an asp.net control of master page in content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have a `Master Page` that have a `asp:Panel` control and the code that sets `Visible = False` in it's code behind.
Now i want to change `Visible = True` in one of content page. How do it?

Master page code behind:

```
AccountUserInfo.Visible = false;
```

Content page code behind:

```
((Panel)Master.FindControl("AccountUserInfo")).Visible = true;
```

Apparently content page's code behind don't work.

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort? Are you sure that line get called?

Comment: @Serge,No,every thing is good and i haven't any error!But it not worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The master page code that set the control to `Visible = False` is being executed after the code on the page.

Try to place the page code on the `PreRender` event. It is the one of the last events of the cycle:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ((Panel)Master.FindControl("AccountUserInfo")).Visible = true; 
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Also, take a look at this [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Diagram](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In the ASP website live cycle, Page's code runs before Master page's code does.

So you're basically just overwrite the "Visible" setting previously set to "true" when in your Master Page you do :  AccountUserInfo.Visible=false;

Also note that if any parent container of AccountUserInfo has a visibility set to false, AccountUserInfo.Visible getter will return false (IMHO: a poor choice Microsoft made there...).

Comment: Look at [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx).  You can also put debug breakpoints in your master page and in your content page, so you can see which one executes first.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

((Panel)Master.FindControl("panel")).Visible = true;

}
```

Hope It helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**in content Page**

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Panel panel = (Panel)Master.FindControl("panel");
    panel.Visible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers might work if the connection between the master page and its control is direct. In other cases you might want to take a look at the hierarchy of the object you're trying to 'find' and change. I.E. FindControl might return null if called from MasterPage (this depends on how your content page is structured, e.g. MasterPage > Menu > MenuItem > control)

so with that in mind you might want to do something like this at the content page code behind:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ParentObj1 = (ParentObj1)Master.FindControl("ParentObj1Id"); 
   ParentObj2 = (ParentObj2)ParentObj1.FindControl("ParentObj1Id"); // or some other function that identifies children objects
   ...
   Control ctrl  = (Control)ParentObjN.FindControl("ParentObjNId"); // or some other function that identifies children objects
   // we change the status of the object
   ctrl.Visible = true;
}
```

or I'll give you an actual snippet that worked for me (make button with id ButtonViewReports hidden at MasterPage, visible at content page):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    // find RadMenu first
    RadMenu rm = (RadMenu)this.Master.FindControl("MenuMaster");
    if (rm != null)
    {
        // find that menu item inside RadMenu
        RadMenuItem rmi = (RadMenuItem)rm.FindItemByValue("WorkspaceMenuItems");
        if (rmi != null)
        {
            // find that button inside that Menitem
            Button btn = (Button)rmi.FindControl("ButtonViewReports");
            if (btn != null)
            {
                // make it visible
                btn.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```